# Extracting value from the output of a webpage, in a better way?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using "requests" to get the source of the webpage,

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
url = 'http://somewebsite'
c.get(url)
print c.content
```

This output me the source, of the webpage, in that source, I have part of code which I need to extract. The part of output is:

```
<b>String: </b><input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrst" /><br /><br />
<form name="submitform" action="some/index.php" method="POST"><br />
    Answer: <br />
    <input size="75" name="solution"><br /><br />
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <input name ="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
```

Here I need to extract the value of variable "value" that is "abcdefghijklmnopqrst", I did accomplished it by split, this way:

```
cool = (c.content).split('</b>')                                          
var1 = cool[1].split(' ')                                                  
var2 = var1[2].split('"')                                               
var3 = var2[1]
print var3
```

This gives me the result.

But, my question is: is there a better way to get the result instead of using multiple variables and multiple splits?

Comment: Yes, use `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Do you know about selenium

Comment: you can easily fetch any attribute on html page